# Separate Out Real Users

Tags: users, security

If I look at

```
/wp-admin/users.php
```

I see all the users, but some have given a bogus email and never used their password.

Is there some way to see who has used their password at least once? If not, is there a plugin to do this going forward?

Comment: Are they activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you install the following plugin and leave that one running for a while... you can see who logged in since using that plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-last-login/

[image]

That seems to do what you need.

As far as I quickly can see it runs on $this->hook( 'wp_login' ) and does:

```
$user   =   get_user_by( 'login', $user_login );
update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'last-login-in-meta-table', time() );
```

Possibly the

```
user-settings-time
```

in the meta table can help somewhat on determining the history before installing the plugin, never used it (see http://wpseek.com/wp_user_settings/)

Comment: It is possible because we can assign a Post to a User, but it's weird to have 21 Posts and never been logged in...

Comment: @brasofilo Didn't notice it, but made my day :)

Comment: I bet that guy is using XMLRPC ...

Comment: User logs in and posts many times, then you add this plug. Last logged in is "never."

Answer (score 2):

Login information like this is not stored anywhere in database. But you can add it for future users. Following code will check for current user meta `user_login_count` on each login and increase it by 1 or set it to '1' on first login.

```
<?php
add_action('wp_login', 'my_count_logins');
function my_count_logins() {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $user_login_count = (int) get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_login_count', true);
    if($user_login_count)
        $user_login_count++;
    else
        $user_login_count = 1;
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'user_login_count', $user_login_count)
}
```

Following code adds additional column `Login count` to the `Users` table:

```
function my_alter_user_table( $column ) {
    $column['user_login_count'] = __('Login count');
    return $column;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'my_alter_user_table' );

function my_alter_user_row( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    switch ($column_name) {
        case 'user_login_count' :
            return get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_login_count', true);
        break;
        default:
    }
    return $return;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'my_alter_user_row', 10, 3 );
```